# What's wrong with this php json script?

Tags: php, json, api, twitter, scripting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

I can't get this php json script to work. I'm trying to get the screen name from twitter, using their api.

Here's what I did.

```
$send_request = file_get_contents('https://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?screen_name=frankmeacey');

$request_contents = json_decode($send_request);

echo $request_contents->screen_name;
```

Why is this returning a blank value every time? I've tried changing things here and there and it's just not working...

Comment: @hakre While the answer to that question would help solve this, they're hardly duplicates. By that logic, every question involving PHP errors is a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the data structure you get back is an array of objects, not an object.

```
echo $request_contents[0]->screen_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

That data looks to be an object inside an array.  Try

```
echo $request_contents[0]->screen_name;
```

Best to check first it is an array and to get the first user from it:

```
if (is_array($request_contents)) {
    $user_info = $request_contents[0];
}

if (isset($user_info)) {
    echo $user_info->screen_name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's

```
$request_contents[0]->screen_name
```

since $request_contents is an array of objects, not the object itself.

Do a

```
var_dump($request_contents);
```

to see the structure of your json.

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
print_r($request_contents);
```

OR

```
var_dump($request_contents);
```

for checking array.

Answer (score 0):

Your page should not be blank .. you should get an error like `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in` since you are calling `$request_contents->screen_name` which is not valid.

Try telling PHP to output all error Using

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

I also prefer CURL its faster

```
$ch = curl_init("https://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?screen_name=frankmeacey");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$request_contents = json_decode($result);
var_dump($request_contents[0]->screen_name);
```

Output

```
 string 'frankmeacey' (length=11)
```